# Cyclic schema giving error as "Error: Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Node"."

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-relay

I am new to 'GraphQL' using nodejs. I am stucked into bi-directional schema mapping. posts <-> authors. Using [graphql](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) and [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) module.

Following are the two schema we are using.

```
--posts.js // here we are requiring authors.js 
const {
    AuthorType,
    schema: AuthorSchema,
    AuthorsConnection
} = require('./authors');

class Post {}

const {
    nodeInterface,
    nodeField
} = nodeDefinitions(
    globalId => {
        const {
            type,
            id
        } = fromGlobalId(globalId);
        // return based on the id
        return DataSource['posts'][0];
    },
    obj => {
        console.log(" : PostType : ", PostType);
        // type to be return 
        return Post;
    }
);

const PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    "name": "PostType",
    "description": "Posts type and it's relevant fields",
    "fields": () => ({
        "id": globalIdField('Post'),
        "title": {
            "type": GraphQLString
        },
        "body": {
            "type": GraphQLString
        },
        "author": {
            "type": AuthorsConnection,
            "resolve": (parent, argument, root, currentSdl) => {
                console.log("v1, v2, v3, v4  :", parent);
                if (parent.author)
                    return connectionFromArray(DataSource['authors'], {})
                return [];
            }
        }
    }),
    isTypeOf: Post,
    interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});

const {
    connectionType: PostsConnection,
    edgeType: GQLPostEdge
} = connectionDefinitions({
    name: "Post",
    nodeType: PostType
});
module.exports = exports = {
    PostType,
    PostsConnection,
    schema: {
        post: nodeField,
        posts: {
            type: PostsConnection,
            resolve: (root, v2, v3) => {
                return connectionFromArray(DataSource['posts'], {});
            }
        }
    }
};

--authors.js // here we have required posts.js

const {
    PostType,
    PostsConnection
} = require('./posts');

class Author {}

const {
    nodeInterface,
    nodeField
} = nodeDefinitions(
    globalId => {
        const {
            type,
            id
        } = fromGlobalId(globalId);
        // return based on the id
        return DataSource['authors'][0];
    },
    obj => {
        console.log(" : Authorype : ", Authorype);
        // type to be return 
        return Author;
    }
);

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    "name": "AuthorType",
    "description": "Author type and it's relevant fields",
    "fields": () => ({
        "id": globalIdField('Author'),
        "firstName": {
            "type": GraphQLString
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": GraphQLString
        },
        authorPosts: {
            type: PostsConnection,
            resolve: (parent, args, root, context) => {
                return connectionFromArray(DataSource['posts'], {});
            }
        }
    }),
    isTypeOf: null,
    interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});

const {
    connectionType: AuthorsConnection,
    edgeType: GQLAuthorEdge
} = connectionDefinitions({
    name: "Author",
    nodeType: AuthorType
});

module.exports = exports = {
    AuthorType,
    AuthorsConnection,
    schema: {
        author: nodeField,
        authors: {
            type: AuthorsConnection,
            resolve: (root, v2, v3) => {
                return connectionFromArray(DataSource['authors'], {});
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Once I merge above schema for GraphQL I am getting following error.

```
Error: Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Node".
```

I tried to debugged this issue, following is I observed following.

- Once I change "authors" field from posts schema to other than
  "AuthorsConnection" it starts working.
- Or if removed "authors" field
  from posts schema it starts working.

Please let me know what is issue here, is it relevant to `nodeDefinitions` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed related to the `nodeDefinitions` function. From the `graphql-relay` docs:

> `nodeDefinitions` returns the `Node` interface that objects can implement, and returns the `node` root field to include on the query type. To implement this, it takes a function to resolve an ID to an object, and to determine the type of a given object.

You're calling this twice, which is resulting in the `Node` type being defined twice, and you're referencing one of each:

```
schema: {
    post: nodeField,

// ...

schema: {
    author: nodeField,
```

This is causing the error - there's now two independent instances of `Node` which is invalid.

The solution is to only call `nodeDefinitions` once, and then pass the reference to the generated `nodeField` and `nodeInterface` to the relevant places. Then your `globalId => {...}` function will need to look at the `type` to figure out how to get the relevant record, be it an author or a post.

Comment: Hi Benjie, Thanks for your quick reply. Calling 'nodeDefinitions' only once did the trick. But is it feasible for large no. of types(like posts, authors etc...) to be fetched from single location. Is there any other modular way of doing it?

Comment: The fetcher is just a function; and from fromGlobalId you get a type; so then you could use that to look into an arbitrary map and call the relevant fetcher (if it exists); so each type can register a fetcher function on the fetcher map. This is just one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Along with above answer given by @Benjie. I find out the way to overcome issues  which was resulting into error of `Error: Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Node".`.

Following are the key points to be check when we are making graphql in modular way.

- Don't create new instances of type, For eg: `const PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({})` it should always send single object rather than new object every time.
- use `nodeDefinations` only once.
- Check for the cyclic issues in common javascript issue which will occurs.

Thanks.